# Salesforce lwc &aura .Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ma')

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura, summer-22

I use aura, replacing the standard create button like this(CreateAccountCompt):

```
<aura:component description="CreateAccountCompt"
                implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,lightning:actionOverride"
                access="global">
    <div>
        <c:createAccount></c:createAccount>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

c:createAccount

c:createAccount is a lightning web component

like this :

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form
            id="recor222313dCreateForm1234123"
            object-api-name="Account">
        <!--国家-->
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Country__c"></lightning-input-field>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

Country__c is a lookup field.
When I can't search for "United States", click "Show All Results for 'United States' ", and the error will be generated.
The stack of javascript looks like this:

```
    aura_prod.js:887 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ma')
    at Object.dispatchGlobalEvent (aura_prod.js:887:85)
    at eval (deprecatedOverlayUtils.js:1:708)
    at Object.n.getAura (auraUtils.js:1:389)
    at eval (deprecatedOverlayUtils.js:1:694)
    at eval (platformOverlayUtils.js:1:4392)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at new b (aura_prod.js:994:269)
    at Object.o.showCustomOverlay (platformOverlayUtils.js:1:4340)
    at eval (deprecatedOverlayUtils.js:1:668)
```

[image]
[image]

When I try other objects and other lookup fields, the same error will be reported.
The current version is Summer '22 Patch 4.5, the previous version Spring '22 Patch 19.9 will not have this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stacktrace -1895801639 points to the error: [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading Q)] which has been identified as a known issue https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002aLwoQAE and is fixed now.